# keeping url parameters during pagination

Tags: php, pagination

Is there any way to keep my GET parameters when paginating.

My problem is that I have a few different urls i.e

```
questions.php?sort=votes&author_id=1&page=3

index.php?sort=answers&style=question&page=4
```

How in my pagination class am I supposed to create a link to the page with a different page number on it but yet still keep the other parts of the url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you just parse the URL and then you add the parameter at the end or replace it if it already exists.

```
$parts = parse_url($url) + array('query' => array());
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$query['page'] = $page;
$parts['query'] = http_build_str($query);
$newUrl = http_build_url($parts);
```

This example code requires the [PHP HTTP module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.http.php) for [`http_build_url`](http://php.net/http_build_url) and [`http_build_str`](http://php.net/http_build_str). The later can be replaced with [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) and for the first one a PHP userspace implementation exists in case you don't have the module installed.

Another alternative is to use the [`Net_URL2`](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2) package which offers an interface to diverse URL operations:

```
$op = new Net_URL2($url);
$op->setQueryVariable('page', $page);
$newUrl = (string) $op;
```

It's more flexible and expressive.

Comment: Is this considered best practice or would you not normally end up with a situation that needs this?

Comment: I would consider it best practice if you wrap it into a function or class so you have easy access to it in your code. Also it re-uses existing functions which is preferable. It works regardless of the number of parameters in the query-info-part of the URL and respects your PHP configuration.

Comment: @yehuda: I added some additional example which uses a well made component to do the job, that's probably better practice.

Answer (score 6):

You could use **[http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)** for this. It's much cleaner than deleting the old parameter by hand.

It should be possible to pass a merged array consisting of $_GET and your new values, and get a clean URL.

```
$new_data = array("currentpage" => "mypage.html");
$full_data = array_merge($_GET, $new_data);  // New data will overwrite old entry
$url = http_build_query($full_data);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you wanted to write your own function that did something like http_build_query, or if you needed to customize it's operations for some reason or another:

```
<?php 
function add_edit_gets($parameter, $value) { 
    $params = array(); 
    $output = "?"; 
    $firstRun = true; 
    foreach($_GET as $key=>$val) { 
        if($key != $parameter) { 
            if(!$firstRun) { 
                $output .= "&"; 
            } else { 
                $firstRun = false; 
            } 
            $output .= $key."=".urlencode($val); 
         } 
    } 

    if(!$firstRun) 
        $output .= "&"; 
    $output .= $parameter."=".urlencode($value); 
    return htmlentities($output); 
} 

?>
```

Then you could just write out your links like:

```
<a href="<?php echo add_edit_gets("page", "2"); ?>">Click to go to page 2</a>
```

Comment: [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) is always available, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the data the function could be of use, I understand as the function sits it would be better to use http_build_query - giving OP options.

Comment: Yes and you should make URL an input parameter instead of using `$_GET` somewhere buried inside. Or at least make `$gets` a parameter of the function.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing your `page` parameter in a session, so you don't have to modify every single page url?

Comment: But how do i change just the page parameter of the url?

Comment: you wouldn't need to. storing and retrieving the value strictly happens on server side and is independent of the actual page links.

Comment: This would be bad practice if you care about SEO and bookmarking functionalities