# How to stop URL query string from repeating?

Tags: php, mysql, url, parameter-passing

I'm using a URL query string to filter MySQL search results. When a user clicks on one of the links the query along with another variable is passed to the application, which then builds and executes a SQL query to the database.

The filtering works - the user can filter by genre, platform and can also sort at the same time, but the problem is that every time they click on a link it adds another variable at the end of `$query`.

For example if the user types in *example* and selects as filter, the genre *action*, the query looks like this:

```
keywords=example&genre=action
```

But lets say they then click on the adventure genre, the query then looks like this:

```
keywords=example&genre=action&genre=adventure
```

Is there a way to get the query to replace a variable if it isalready set?

```
$query = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]))); 

<div id="filter_nav">
        <ul  id="nav_form">
            <li><h3 id="h3">Genre: &nbsp;</h3>
            <li><a href="search.php?'.$query.'&genre=Fighting">Fighting</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php?'.$query.'&genre=Role-Playing">Role-Playing</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php?'.$query.'&genre=Action">Action</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul  id="nav_form">
            <li><h3 id="h3">Platform: &nbsp;</h3>
            <li><a href="search.php?'.$query.'&platform=Playstation 3">PS3</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php?'.$query.'&platform=xbox 360">Xbox 360</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php?'.$query.'&platform=Gamecube">Gamecube</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        ';
        echo '
        <ul  id="sorting_form">
            <li><h3 id="h3">SORT BY: &nbsp;</h3>
            <li><a href="search.php?'.$query.'&order=title">Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php?'.$query.'&order=release_date">Date</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php?'.$query.'&order=rating">Rating</a></li>

        </ul>
        ';

function search_results($keywords){
$returned_results = array();
$where = "";

$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
$total_keywords = count($keywords);

foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
    $where .= "title LIKE '%$keyword%'";
    if($key != ($total_keywords - 1)){
        $where .= " AND ";
    }   
}
if (isset($_GET['platform']) && !empty($_GET['platform'])){
    $platform = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_GET['platform']))); 
        $where .= " AND platform='$platform'";
    }

if (isset($_GET['genre']) && !empty($_GET['genre'])){
    $genre = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_GET['genre']))); 
                $where .= " AND genre='$genre'";
}

if (isset($_GET['order']) && !empty($_GET['order'])){
    $order = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_GET['order'])));
    $where .= " ORDER BY $order DESC";
    }

$results ="SELECT * FROM games WHERE $where ";
```

Comment: you prevent that by [properly buildiong the new URL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9667076/367456).

Comment: possible duplicate of [keeping url parameters during pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666909/keeping-url-parameters-during-pagination)

Comment: Thanks i'll check out the post. I've been searching for a while i guess i was using wrong keywords.

Answer (score 2):

Using your code it can be done de-constructing the query string using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and rebuilding it using [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for every link.

However, personally I would just go for a form with 3 select boxes where the previously selected values are pre-selected.

You could put all your selection options in one multi-dimensional array and do a double loop.

Example:

```
<?php
$options = array(
  "genre" => array("Fighting", "Role-Playing", ...),
  ...
);
foreach $options as $key => $value)
{
?>
<select name="<?php echo $key; ?>">
<?php 
  foreach ($value as $item)
  {
    // echo option for item and mark it selected if necessary
  }
?>
</select>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Interesting, i'll try it out and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Modify every `<a>` tag like:
`<a href="search.php?'.$query.'&genre=Fighting">Fighting</a>`
to
`<a href="search.php?&genre=Fighting">Fighting</a>`

I.e remove `'.$query.'` part.

Comment: Wouldn't that make you loose all the other parameters?

Comment: `is there a way to get the query to replace the variable if its already set?`