# Check if url contains parameters

Tags: php, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [keeping url parameters during pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666909/keeping-url-parameters-during-pagination)

I want to add a parameter to the current url with php, but how do I know if the url already contains a parameter?

Example:

foobar.com/foo/bar/index.php => foobar.com/foo/bar/index.php?myparameter=5
foobar.com/index.php?foo=7 => foobar.com/index.php?foo=7&myparameter=5

The main problem is that I don't know if I need to add a "?".

My code (found it somewhere, but it doesn't work):

```
<?php   if(/?/.test(self.location.href)){ //if url contains ?
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]&myparameter=5";
} else {
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?myparameter=5"; 
}?>
```

Comment: @Puyol, you shouldn't use constants as array keys, instead wrap in curly brackets or break out of the string and concatenate. `"http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}..."`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The URL parameters are received from a global variable called `$_GET` which is in fact an array. So, to know if a URL contains a parameter, you can use `isset()` function.

```php
if (isset($_GET['yourparametername'])) {
    //The parameter you need is present
}
```

Afterwards, you can create separate array of such parameter you need to attach to a URL. Like:

```php
if(isset($_GET['param1'])) {
    \\The parameter you need is present
    $attachList['param1'] = $_GET['param1'];
}
if(isset($_GET['param2'])) {
    $attachList['param2'] = $_GET['param2];
}
```

Now, to know whether or not, you need a `?` symbol, just count this array

```php
if(count($attachList)) {
    $link .= "?";
    // and so on
}
```

**Update:**

To know if any parameter is set, just count the `$_GET`

```php
if(count($_GET)) {
     //some parameters are set
}
```

Comment: I don't want to know if my parameter is set, I want to know if any parameter is set

Comment: actually, it's still possible to have a url like this: http://example.com/?   so in this way there are no parameteres but he still should not add ? char

Comment: `count($_GET) ? '&' : '?'`

Comment: I add `empty` in your Update as in; `if(empty(count($_GET))){` when has no params :p :)

Comment: What about mod-rewritten URLs -- count($_GET) would always be set for them?

Answer (score 21):

Really you should be using the [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
<?php
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if(isset($url['query'])){
    //Has query params
}else{
    //Has no query params
}
?>
```

Also you should enclose your array based variables in curly brackets or break out of the string:

`$url = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}?myparameter=5";`

or

`$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?myparameter=5";`

enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and you will see the error. Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' ect

Comment: By using PHP_URL_PATH as the second param for parse_url it does not pass $url['query'], so your isset($url['query']) will always be false. Simply remove PHP_URL_PATH as a second param to work correctly. Thank you for your answer as it makes more sense to me when $_GET is not available to use.

Answer (score 7):

you can search for the '?' char like this:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], '?')) { // returns false if '?' isn't there
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]&myparameter=5";
} else {
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?myparameter=5"; 
}
```

Comment: Or in short, 
 `<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]".((strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?'))?'&':'?')."myparameter=5"`.   
thanks for the coolest trick.