# check whether ANY variable of type $_GET exists

Tags: php

I know that I can check whether a particular `$_GET` variable exists with

```
isset($_GET['foo'])
```

But how can I check whether *any* `$_GET` variable exists? I thought that it would be as simple as

```
isset($_GET)
```

But that does not work. It always evaluates as `true`, even if there are no parameters in the URL.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `$_GET` is a [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) variable, and is "always" set, but can be empty. _"that are always available in all scopes"_. Also `isset()` checks if the variable is set, not if it's empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if url contains parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868818/check-if-url-contains-parameters)

Comment: `$_GET` is [a normal associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) like any other in PHP, so you check whether it has any entries in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$_GET` is an associative array, you could check if it's empty or not, with the [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.

```php
empty($_GET);
```

You can test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/831a1ac8b828ae3f7e04b35f7d292406fccb00f5)

P.S. the `empty` function works on multiple data types, not just associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count`:

```
// if get is empty
count($_GET) > 0 // false

// if get contains some key value pairs
count($_GET) > 0 // true
```