# Removing the variables in url

Tags: php, html, get

Before I am told to look at other posts that are similar, please note that I have tried to apply them but to no avail.

I need to clear the variables in the url after a series of if statements are true. I have the following code:

```
<?php


$_SESSION['passlevel']='0'; 

if ($_SESSION['passlevel'] == '0')

{
if(isset($_GET['box_1_color']))
{
$color=$_GET['box_1_color'];
    if($color == "#800080")
    {
    echo "you have passed step one.";

    $_SESSION['passlevel'] = '1';

    // add something that removes url string



    }
    else 
    {
    echo "you didn't select purple.";

    }   
}
else echo "login with your colorlock passcode.";

}

if ($_SESSION['passlevel'] == '1')

{
if(isset($_GET['box_1_color']))
{
$color=$_GET['box_1_color'];
    if($color == "#DD7500")
    {
    echo "you have passed step two.";
    $_SESSION['passlevel']='2'; 
            // add something that removes url string

    }
    else 
    {
    echo "you didn't select orange.";

    }   
}
else echo "enter remaining colors.";

}


?>
```

This is for color dependent password that has the background of each of 10 divs change to one of 10 colors after a div is clicked on (note that some of the echoes are only there for now as a method of debugging). The information is sent to the url through multiple forms:

```
<form> 
<div id="box1" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box1color ?>'/> 
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box1color'/> 
</form>

<form>
<div id="box2" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box2color ?>'/>
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box2color'/> 
</form>

<form>
<div id="box3" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box3color ?>'/> 
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box3color'/> 
</form>

<form>
<div id="box4" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box4color ?>'/>  
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box4color'/> 
</form>

<form>
<div id="box5" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box5color ?>'/>  
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box5color'/> 
</form>

<form>
<div id="box6" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box6color ?>'/> 
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box6color'/> 
</form>

<form>
<div id="box7" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box7color ?>'/> 
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box7color'/> 
</form>

<form>
<div id="box8" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box8color ?>'/>
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box8color'/>
</form>

<form>
<div id="box9" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box9color ?>'/>
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box9color'/>
</form>

<form>
<div id="box10" class="box" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'></div>
<input type='hidden' name='box_1_color' value='<?php echo $box10color ?>'/> 
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='box10color'/> 
</form>
```

An example of the url after one of the colors (purple) is selected:
        `http://localhost/colorlock/index.php?box_1_color=%23800080&name=box9color`

So I want to remove the ?box_1_color=%23800080&name=box9color part. How could i remove it where the code says "// add something that removes url string" so that when the next block of code is initiated it doesnt run immediately with the same color code in the url before a user can select their next color?

I hope my question is clear (i understand that it a confusing) and i hope that it is answerable. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [keeping url parameters during pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666909/keeping-url-parameters-during-pagination) - probably you have not found it because of the title, the answer tells you how you can modify url parameters easily incl. unsetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one/some of 3 things:

1. Use POST. This is a good idea but it would still be best combined with...
2. Redirect to the same page without the URL arguments after processing the form.
3. Use ajax to process the user input.

The easiest of these to integrate with your existing code is probably a combination of 1 and 2. To do this, add these lines where your comment is:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
exit;
```

...and change all the `<form>` elements in your HTML so that they read:

```
<form method="post">
```

...and obviously change all occurrences of `$_GET` in your PHP code to `$_POST`

Comment: I wish I can have multiple vote up buttons! 
The refresh problem is something that really worth noting!

Comment: This is very helpful, and seems to work, but the issue is that when the page refreshes itself, the <code>$_SESSION['passlevel'] = '1';</code> line does not work or the original <code>$_SESSION['passlevel'] = '0';</code> line is called again, either way the first conditional statement, the one that calls for <code>$_SESSION['passlevel']</code> to equal zero runs again whereas it needs to run the second conditional, the one that calls for <code>$_SESSION['passlevel']</code> to equal one.

Comment: When the page reloads, the $_SESSION['passlevel'] is again set to 0 at the top of the php tag. This makes it so the first conditional block runs regardless of however many times they have clicked on a color. How could i define the 'passlevel' so that the user doesnt run the first chuck of code over and over again?

Comment: @ryno Change the first line to `if (empty($_SESSION['passlevel'])) { $_SESSION['passlevel'] = '0'; }` so that it is only initialise to 0 if it is not yet set.

Comment: almost there, now the issue is then when i select the purple square, it reloads the page but still shows the echo "login with your colorlock passcode." However, then when i click on orange (the next correct color) it is okay... why is still showing the first condition's else statement while it runs the second statement?

Comment: weird, that is only happening in firefox, chrome has it working correctly.

Comment: @ryno Probably something is screwy in your session data in Firefox from something else you did while developing. Try clearing you cookies in FF, close it an reopen it and try again, and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: nah still wont run that second click.

Comment: @ryno Did you change `$_GET` to `$_POST`? Maybe try using `$_REQUEST` instead?

Comment: yeah using post, ill try to implement request

Answer (score 1):

Could you use POST instead of GET?  You use $_POST in your PHP instead of $_GET and you never have to worry about what's in the URL - it's always clean.

Comment: I suppose it is possible, but when i replace the GETs with POSTs i get nothing, the php doesnt run and just shows the original else statement of "echo "login with your colorlock passcode.";" So I would need you to explain how to implement it a bit in the circumstances above. Also, would applying POST rid me of the problem of the second set of conditional statement running with the first color still in the url?

Comment: You'll also need to update the submit() function to use POST as well.  Otherwise submit() is using GET and your PHP is using POST and that won't get you any results.  You may want to post the submit() function if you need help changing it.  If you use POST, you won't pass any parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
unset($_GET['box_1_color']);
```

in aproriate place of your code

Comment: This doesn't work - OP wants to hide it from the URL - not from the script. 
You code should do the trick when unsetting items for sure though.