# php add variable to url without remove exiting

Tags: php, url, pagination, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [keeping url parameters during pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666909/keeping-url-parameters-during-pagination)

Currently I've pagination that is passing a variable as `"?page=1"`. The url variable of `"?page=1"` is dynamically changed for instance `"?page=3"` and so on. The problem is, when I have a few action for my site, like as `"?action=show_post` or `?action=show_categories` and etc". So If I click my pagination number the variable `"?action=show_post"` will be removed from my url.

My question is: How to add a variable to an `url` and will be like this `"?action=anything&page=anything"` and "anything key just for term or parable and will change dynamically value"

Comment: Fetch current url, and add/replace this parameter... Where is the problem?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666909/keeping-url-parameters-during-pagination

Comment: the problem is when i click my pagination number, for instance "i clicked 1" and it or url will be sent "?page=1" and existing variable "?action=show_post" will be removed" or change. so i want the exiting "?action=show_post" isn't to be removed or keep on and will add an url varible so the complete view on my webbrowser be like this "http://localhost?action=show_post&page=1"

Answer (score 0):

Yes,, you will need to use the Hidden $_POST method for those. 
input type="hidden" value= php echo $page['number'];  etc---- !

Comment: thanks before. i need the function. for $page=number i used the looping. my question is, how to add variable to url that has existing url variable too. for instance my current webbrowser url is "localhost/?action=show_post"; if i click my paging that borrow an url to as link by value 1,2, or etc, it will remove my existing url, so the url will be like this "http:://localhost?page=1" that i want should be like this "http:://localhost?action=show_post&page=1"

Answer (score 0):

If your link is something like `<a href="http://domain/page.php?page=2">`..., just do it this way:

```
$querystring=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
<a href="http://domain/page.php?page=2&<?php echo $querystring ?>>
```

You get the query parameters in the current URL (`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`) and you just add them to your target URL in your link. That is all. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: should be like this "http://localhost/?action=show_post&page=1"