# pass parameters to pagination url

Tags: php, url, pdo

I am thing of a way to pass about 15 parameters to a url pagination:

for example I have:

```
$input = $_GET['input'];
$categories = $_GET['category'];
$state = $_GET['state'];
$zipcode = $_GET['zipcode'];
```

I could do it this way and works fine:

```
 $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev&input=".$_GET['input']."& 
 category=".$_GET['category']."&state=".$_GET['state']."& 
 zipcode=".$GET['zipcode']."'>Previous</a>";
```

But I have a lot more Parameters to pass. Could someone show me how it's done using an array or anything better?

Thank you

Comment: What you have appears to be the simplest and most standard way when dealing with a GET request.  Why obfuscate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo can use this function:
 [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

php.net example:

```
<?php
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');

?>
```

Output:

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor
```

Answer (score 3):

A function that turns an array into a URL query is available in PHP, it is called:

- [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query)

The usage is pretty straight forward:

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');
```

The above example will output:

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor
```

I recommend [the manual page just linked](http://php.net/http_build_query) for more information.

If you're looking for something object-oriented, the [`Net_URL2` Pear Package](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/) is useful.

It also allows to change some parameters conditionally, which is normally very useful for pagination, see [my answer to *"keeping url parameters during pagination"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9667076/367456) for two examples, one Array/PHP standard extension based, and another one for `Net_URL2`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the `$_GET` keys are the same as the parameter names in the URL, you could do this:

```
$url = $targetpage . '?page=' . $prev . '&';

foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
    $url .= $k . '=' . $v . '&';
}
 $paginate.= "<a href='$url'>Previous</a>";
```

.. Or you could just use PHP's [inbuilt function `http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)